# How to convert a uint64 into uint?

Tags: go

I have the following function:

```
func (rc ResizeController) Resize(c *gin.Context) {

    height := c.Query("height")
    width := c.Query("width")
    filepath := c.Query("file")

    h, err := strconv.ParseUint(height, 10, 32)
    w, err := strconv.ParseUint(width, 10, 32)

    file, err := os.Open("./test_images/" + filepath)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    image, err := jpeg.Decode(file)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    m := resize.Resize(1000, 100, image, resize.Lanczos3)

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    jpeg.Encode(buf, m, nil)
    response := buf.Bytes()

    c.Data(200, "image/jpeg", response)
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
controllers/resize_controller.go:41: cannot use h (type uint64) as type uint in argument to resize.Resize
controllers/resize_controller.go:41: cannot use w (type uint64) as type uint in argument to resize.Resize
```

I've tried a few different functions from the strconv lib with no luck!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No need to use any of the `strconv` functions; just do a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to `uint`:

```
h64, err := strconv.ParseUint(height, 10, 32)
if err != nil {
    // TODO: handle error
}
w64, err := strconv.ParseUint(width, 10, 32)
if err != nil {
    // TODO: handle error
}
h := uint(h64)
w := uint(w64)
```

Comment: I'm getting:

`controllers/resize_controller.go:26: multiple-value strconv.ParseUint() in single-value context
controllers/resize_controller.go:27: multiple-value strconv.ParseUint() in single-value context`
now

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfect.